# Interpreting Keras Model Predict Output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, data-science

I have fit the mnist digit Keras/TF example.

```
digits_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
)

model.fit(
    x=train_images,
    y=train_labels,
    epochs=6,
    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),
)
```

The sparse categorical accuracy got up to about 94.5%

At this point I was to run one of the training examples back through the model to see what the output looks like. I believe you would use the predict function to do this. I had to do a little reshaping of the training example data (which may be the issue I am having here and for which there are other posts but none conclusive)

I think the results are reasonable

```
image_in = train_images[0][ np.newaxis, :, : ] # reshape
predict = model.predict(image_in)
print(predict, train_labels[0])

image_in2 = train_images[1][ np.newaxis, :, : ] # reshape
predict = model.predict(image_in2)
print(predict, train_labels[1])

image_in3 = train_images[2][ np.newaxis, :, : ] # reshape
predict = model.predict(image_in3)
print(predict, train_labels[2])

image_in4 = train_images[3][ np.newaxis, :, : ] # reshape
predict = model.predict(image_in4)
print(predict, train_labels[3])
```

> [[-15.103473   20.778965   -9.244939   62.400173  -23.793236
> 72.29711    -2.7528331  12.732147   37.075775   36.81269  ]] 5
>
> [[ -1.3534731 -24.39009   -14.5208435 -20.452188  -16.758095
> -12.028614   -13.0093565  -9.06416   -11.541512  -14.997495 ]] 0
>
> [[-9.685611   18.384281   13.8173685  -0.23191524 37.27173
> 18.273088   -1.4883347  26.91457    11.042679   25.099646  ]] 4
>
> [[ 11.550052    37.031742    -0.43448153   2.1549647    6.6804423
> 1.829277    11.534891     4.703198     1.562077   -14.293095  ]] 1

There is a mapping between the label and the index of the output that contains the largest number.

So I decided to run some tests on numbers I drew.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So it appeared that the MNIST were white on a black background, so I did a little transformation when loading the images

```
image_file = Image.open('mysix.png')
image_file = ImageOps.grayscale(image_file)
mysix = np.invert(np.array(image_file))
image_in = mysix[ np.newaxis, :, : ] # reshape
predict = model.predict(image_in)
print(predict)
cv2.imwrite("real_test.png", mysix)
```

The outputs were not so convincing

- This for the 6 [Incorrect]

> [[-11.062315   -3.6117797 -12.970709   -3.692216  -20.52597
> 6.8898406    -6.7844076  -4.1480203  -8.589685   -8.556881 ]]

- This is for the three [Correct]

> [[-30.695564  -23.397968  -21.212194   24.455023  -31.399946
> 10.118337   -82.92692   -10.150092   -5.8821173 -12.108372 ]]

- This if for the seven [Incorrect]

> [[ 1.2403618  4.0243044  9.859227   9.83745   -6.681723   2.4680052
> -7.4165597  6.6975245  3.355576  -9.518949 ]]

1. Is the way I reshape the data to evaluate it with the trained model correct?
2. Is all the data processing I am doing in my code to load the greyscale PNG's legitimate?
3. If both 1 and 2 are true, what explanation is there for the apparent shortcoming of the model that works at a 95% clip on the mnist evaluation set at the end of my 6th training epoch but only 33% on my (albeit limited) evaluation set?

Comment: Simple, your images are too different from the MNIST dataset.

Comment: Isn't the point of the dataset to be an accurate subset/representation of "all" images? I thought that was the power of these types of algorithms. You give a good representation all images and the algorithm picks up on patterns so it can classify outside of the training subset

Comment: No, the MNIST dataset has never had that intention, its only 60K images, its an academic dataset.

Comment: Also with a simple ANN, you are just matching raw pixels, not learning high level patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to convolution neural network similar to what is shown in this excellent MIT video at 41 minutes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjtX1N_VT9E (addressing the point that Frightera mentioned above)

[image]

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1), data_format="channels_last"),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

I probably need to do more evaluation, but over 6 epochs the network got up to a sparse categorical accuracy of 99.63%, significantly better than previous implementation also correctly categorized my three hand drawn digits.